# STL-style algorithm: returning via OutputIterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

I am trying to implement an algorithm that merges elements in an ordered container, if they satisfy a BinaryPredicate.

```
template <typename ForwardIt, 
          typename OutputIt, 
          typename BinaryPredicate, 
          typename Merge>
void merge_adjacent(ForwardIt first, 
                    ForwardIt last, 
                    OutputIt out, 
                    BinaryPredicate pred, 
                    Merge merge)
{
    if(first != last)
        *out = *(first++);
    while(first != last)
    {
        if(pred(*first, *out))
            *out = merge(*out, *(first++));
        else
            *(++out) = *(first++);
    }
}
```

When I pass an empty container to put the result in (via OutputIterator), I get an segmentation fault - I also understand why, because the container does not have any space reserved... When I reserve enough space before passing the OutputIterator, the container stays empty...

I am a lil puzzled because I was following an example implementation of the std::transform function on cppreference:

```
template< class InputIt,
          class OutputIt,
          class UnaryOperation >
OutputIt transform( InputIt first1,
                    InputIt last1,
                    OutputIt d_first, 
                    UnaryOperation unary_op )
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My main.cpp for completeness:

```
#include "merge_adjacent.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Sale
{
public:
    Sale(int date, double amount)
     : date(date),
       amount(amount)
    {}
    Sale()
     : date(0),
       amount(0)
    {}
    int getDate() const
    {
        return date;
    }
    double getAmount() const
    {
        return amount;
    }
private:
    int date;
    double amount;
};

bool sameDate(Sale const& sale1, Sale const& sale2)
{
    return sale1.getDate() == sale2.getDate();
}

Sale mergeSales(Sale const& sale1, Sale const& sale2)
{
    if (sale1.getDate() != sale2.getDate()) throw ;
    
    return Sale(sale1.getDate(), sale1.getAmount() + sale2.getAmount());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Sale> sales = {Sale{1,2.9}, Sale(1,2.2),Sale(1,4.7),Sale(2,1.9),Sale(3,3.8),Sale(3,1.1),Sale(5,2.9),Sale(6,2.9),Sale(6,2.9)};
    std::vector<Sale> merged;
    merged.reserve(20);
    merge_adjacent(sales.begin(), sales.end(), merged.begin()/*std::back_inserter(merged)*/, sameDate, mergeSales);
    std::cout << "size of merged must be 5: " << merged.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what should happen when `out` is an iterator of an empty container?

Comment: is `back_inserter` not working either?

Comment: Calling `reserve` does not resize the vector nor does any of your `merge_adjacent` cause this to happen. All `reserve` does is to ensure the backing data structure has room for at least as many elements as the argument tells it. If you ever go with a non-trivially constructible/destructible element type, could very well result in undefined behaviour, since the storage you're writing to may not have been initialized using the default constructor... Algorithms like the ones discussed here rely on the memory being initialised.

Comment: This is why usually an iterator is returned so that you know where the range written ends. This would allow you to use `merged.erase(myfunction(...), merged,end());` to get a properly sized result.

Comment: When you are passing a "normal" iterator into an empty container to `merge_adjacent`, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of incrementing the iterator past the end of the container. When you are passing `back_inserter`, your program exhibits undefined behavior because it requires a *ForwardIterator* for `out`, but `back_inserter` only supports *OutputIterator*. You are placing requirements on `out` that an *OutputIterator* doesn't provide - you are reading from it (an *OutputIterator* is write-only) and you are accessing it more than once (an *OutputIterator* is single-pass).

Comment: To make your algorithm work with `back_inserter`, you need to arrange it so that the only way you ever use `out` is of the form `*out++ = something;` (just what `transform` is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
template <typename InputIt, 
          typename OutputIt, 
          typename BinaryPredicate, 
          typename Merge>
void merge_adjacent(InputIt first, 
                    InputIt last, 
                    OutputIt out, 
                    BinaryPredicate pred, 
                    Merge merge)
{
    if (first == last) return;
    auto accum = *first++;
    while (first != last) {
        auto cur = *first++;
        if (pred(cur, accum)) {
            accum = merge(accum, cur);
        } else {
            *out++ = accum;
            accum = cur;
        }
    }
    *out++ = accum;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4G384a858). Not tested very thoroughly, I only confirmed it worked on your example. I think I'm staying within the capabilities of *InputIterator* and *OutputIterator*, but I haven't tested that either.